# How to create a Case-Insensitive regex in eve rest framework

Tags: python, regex, mongodb-query, restful-architecture, eve

I am using EVE REST Framework and POSTMAN

In my web API the search for a particular value takes place only when the exact match for the field value is given. It is case sensitive I would like make case insensitive search so that i could retrieve all the values matching the search criteria even if the search term is not given fully.

```
'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
```

If I type just a or A I want all the values that start with a and A to be fetched.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query example would be:

```
/?where={"field":{"$regex":"^(?i)value.*"} }
```

This would find all documents where `field` has values starting with "value", case insensitive ("Value", "value", "VALUE", etc.)

Remember though, by default `$regex` is blacklisted in Eve (`MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST = ['$where', '$regex']`). So if you really want it enabled, you also have to add this line to you `settings.py`:

```
MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST = ['$where']
```

Comment: @Nicola_Iarocci  I have added the `Mongo_Query` line to my settings.py but i have not changed my url. but it not working. 
Actually my mongodb contains a list of cities and when a user starts typing in the search box i want them to be provided with the list matching their search with each character they enter.

Answer (score 1):

`(?i)a.*` matches both 'apple' and 'Apple'.
`(?i)` makes the following regex case insensitive.
Appending also works as in `a.*(?i)`